# Xamarin forms app crashing after auto start on boot

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a xamarin forms application. I added a broadcast receiver to auto start the app on boot. I restarted the phone and app auto started correctly but after around 2 minutes app crashes. Please note that app only crashing in case of auto start on boot.

Testing device: Samsung Galaxy S8 (Android 9) and some android tv devices

Following things already tried.

1. Foreground service
2. Tried to exclude app from battery optimization but nothing worked.

AppManifest

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
    <application android:label="ABC" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:banner="@drawable/banner">
        <receiver android:name=".MyCustomReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    public class MyCustomReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            
            if(Intent.ActionBootCompleted.Equals(intent.Action))
            {
                Intent actIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
                actIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity(actIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Crash Trace:

```
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
BaseDexClassLoader.java, line 134
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class " com.abc.app.MyCustomReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]

dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass BaseDexClassLoader.java:134
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass ClassLoader.java:379
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass ClassLoader.java:312
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver AppComponentFactory.java:84
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver ActivityThread.java:3561
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 ActivityThread.java:237
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:1796
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:106
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:214
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:7045
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:493
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:964

android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver ActivityThread.java:3568
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 ActivityThread.java:237
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:1796
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:106
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:214
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:7045
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:493
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:964

--------------------------------

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver  com.abc.app.MyCustomReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class " com.abc.app.MyCustomReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver ActivityThread.java:3568
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 ActivityThread.java:237
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage ActivityThread.java:1796
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:106
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:214
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:7045
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:493
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:964
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class " com.abc.app.MyCustomReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ com.abc.app-l5EOpz_TN-hTJakX5ZMe5Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass BaseDexClassLoader.java:134
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass ClassLoader.java:379
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass ClassLoader.java:312
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver AppComponentFactory.java:84
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver ActivityThread.java:3561
```

Comment: Do you have any logging or crash/error reporting setup?  You need to determine the cause of the crash before you can fix it

Comment: You need to describe your problem in detail. If you are getting an error code, you should share the log data. You must check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Jason please check I have added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

On problem in your code, you didn't add tag `android:exported` for your `BroadcastReceiver`

Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true,Exported =true,DirectBootAware =true)] 
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class MyCustomReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, Resource.String.test,ToastLength.Long).Show();

        if (Intent.ActionBootCompleted.Equals(intent.Action))
        {
            Intent actIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            actIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            context.StartActivity(actIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

In Android 8.0 (API 26 and above), [Google placed limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) on what apps can do while users aren't directly interacting with them. These limitations affect background services and implicit broadcast receivers such as `Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted`. Because of these limitations, you might have difficulties registering a `Boot Completed` broadcast receiver on newer versions of Android. If this is the case, note that these restrictions do not apply to foreground services, which can be called from your broadcast receiver.

Comment: I already tried this but still not working.

Comment: I noticed that the version of  your test devices is Android 9, [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) should cause this problem.

Comment: thank you for your time. Currently my app is working fine on android 9 but it does not even launch after phone restart on android 11 (samsung). any idea what to do?

Comment: Is there any log about this?

Comment: did not find any log for that. It seems something is missing for latest androids.

Comment: From document [Broadcast Receivers in Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers),we can find that these limitations affect background services and implicit broadcast receivers such as `Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted`. Because of these limitations, you might have difficulties registering a `Boot Completed` broadcast receiver on newer versions of Android. If this is the case, note that these restrictions do not apply to foreground services, which can be called from your broadcast receiver.